# How to ignore commas in a string content?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

How do I make the value with commas as one value? Everytime I run my code, it will not be read as one.

For example the values: "Dry, Damp, or Wet Location Listed - CAN" and the value "Dry, Damp, or Wet Location Listed - USA"

```
Sub Dosomething()
  Dim xSh As Worksheet
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  For Each xSh In Worksheets
      xSh.Select
      Call DeleteColumns
  Next
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Sub DeleteColumns()
  Dim ColumnsToDelete As String, V As Variant
  ColumnsToDelete = "cUPC Certified, Dark Sky Compliant, DECT 6.0 Compliant, DIN EN 12935 Certified, Dry, Damp, or Wet Location Listed - CAN, Dry, Damp, or Wet Location Listed - USA, EEP Compliant, EIA Compliant, EISA 2007 Compliant, EISA Compliant"
  On Error Resume Next
  For Each V In Split(ColumnsToDelete, ",")
    Rows(1).Find(Trim(V), , , xlWhole, , , False).EntireColumn.Delete
  Next
  On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: since you're defining the string in code, why don't you use another character/delimter instead of the comma? Perhaps a "|"? That way, you can leave the "needed" commas in place and split by the "|" character.

Comment: @amadbear It's working now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad it's working. I figured I'd move comment/answer as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you're defining the string in code, why don't you use another character/delimter instead of the comma? Perhaps a "|"? That way, you can leave the "needed" commas in place and split by the "|" character.